# Rails: error when I try to access to a model from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to access to a model from a controller

Path:

```
/controllers
    /admin
        quizzes_controller.rb
/models
    test.rb
```

Controller:

```
class Admin::QuizzesController < ApplicationController

    ...

    def new
        @admin_quiz = Test.new

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.json { render :json => @admin_quiz }
        end
    end

    ...
end
```

Model:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :description, :random_answers, :random_questions, :time_limit

    ...
end
```

Routes:

```
Quiz::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin do 
        resources :tests, :quizzes
    end

    ...
end
```

When I try to access to http://localhost:3000/admin/quizzes/new, I get this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"tests", :format=>nil}
```

If I change my routes.rb file to:

```
Quiz::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin do 
        resources :quizzes
    end

    resources :tests

    ...
end
```

I can access to http://localhost:3000/admin/quizzes/new but when I submit the form I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant TestsController
```

Why?!

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, you didn't mention any controller TestsController so... it's not uninitialized because you didn't create any.

Comment: Nope, still happens... But I want to access to Test model, why I need another controller? 
In Zend for example I can do $user = new Zend_User_Model() to access to a model from any controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that routes only match incoming requests to controllers. They have nothing to do with models themselves. Using the `resources` method, however, you are telling rails that there is a controller responding to the 7 REST methods, named 'model'sController. In your case you are saying that there are TestsController and QuizzesController in the admin namespace.

The error when submitting the form depends on what you are telling the form to submit to. When you don't specify a certain route in the `form_for` helper, rails uses the model to determine the path. In your case that would be TestsController#new since you are (probably) passing a Test instance.

You could change the `form_for`'s action, though, by passing the `:url` option. Check the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) for details. Note that things are a little different when using namespaces:

```
<%Q form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

(from the api)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to keep names more convention based, which is a core rails principle.

Currently there is

a `quizzes` controller with...
 an `@admin_quiz` variable that...
 Uses the `Test` model.

I would start without the namespace and have:

a `quizzes` controller with...
 an `@quiz` variable that...
 Uses the `Quiz` model.

or

a `tests` controller with...
 an `@test` variable that...
 Uses the `Test` model.

and I would remove the `attr_accessible` fields unless you need them due to authentication or something.

Get it all working and commit the code, then work on adding the namespace in.

Comment: My first model was called quizzes but rails gave me an error because the project had the same name.

Now I created a new scaffold Admin::test that refers to the model test.rb into /models, same error: uninitialized constant TestsController.

Comment: I think the problem is that I call the test model (into /models/test.rb) from the controller Admin::test (into /controllers/admin/tests_controller.rb).

Comment: to echo Michael Durant, I'd be careful to keep model names singular and controller names plural. RoR is all about convention over configuration so in order for things to fall into place easily, you should stay as close to convention as possible...